# Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. With timer

Tags: reactjs

```
Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the Clock component.
```

Why is this error keeping being displayed ?? When I log out from my app this warning starts to appear on the console. Could anybody explain why that happens ?

```
const Clock = React.createClass({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            currentTime: moment.utc().format(formatter)
        };
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        const tickId = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
        this.setState({tickId: tickId});
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        clearInterval(this.state.tickId);
    },

    tick: function() {
        this.setState({
            currentTime: moment.utc().format(formatter)
        });
    },

    render() {
        return <span>{this.state.currentTime}</span>;
    }
});
```

Comment: Does "tick" need binding when called by interval?  Otherwise, please put in the clearInterval code so we can see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ran into a similar issue before. What was happening in my case, I was correctly canceling the interval, but there would be times where it would cancel after already calling the function again. What I needed was a way to know if the component was still mounted or not. Unfortunately, React doesn't expose a components mounted state (or at least not easily). So I ended up keeping track of the mounted state myself and then checking if the component was still mounted when calling my interval function.

```
const Clock = React.createClass({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            currentTime: moment.utc().format(formatter)
        };
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        this._isMounted = true;
        const tickId = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
        this.setState({tickId: tickId});
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        this._isMounted = false;
        clearInterval(this.state.tickId);
    },

    tick: function() {
        if(this._isMounted) {
            this.setState({
                currentTime: moment.utc().format(formatter)
            });
        }
    },

    render() {
        return <span>{this.state.currentTime}</span>;
    }
});
```

Comment: this is perfect! Thanks ! But i thought `isMounted` is deprecated, no ???

Comment: that's just a made up property, you can call it anything

Comment: Exactly as @MattLo said, you can name that whatever you want since it's something we keep track of on our own.

Answer (score 1):

No need to store the `tickId` in state.

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    this.tickId = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
},

componentWillUnmount: function() {
    clearInterval(this.tickId);
}
```

Comment: I thought the same thing, although I'm not sure if this will fix their issue.